# Entity Framework Core Auto Increment not working correctly

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

While trying to insert data using my ASP.NET MVC API, the id being auto generated by Entity Framework seems to be out of bounds causing problems to insert into SQL Server. The object has all the data required to be passed in and the database and already been created using a migration. I'm unsure what is causing this error. Thanks in advance for the help

An example of the id generated:

[image: id being a negative value]

This is how I insert the data into the database

```
_context.Triggers.Add(trigger);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

The model class:

```
 [Key]
 public int Id { get; set; }
 [Required]
 public int TriggerType { get; set; } //1 overload, 2 power off
 [Required]
 public string UserId { get; set; }
 [Required]
 public string Name { get; set; }
```

Comment: what's this: `_context.Triggers.Add(trigger);`?

Comment: @LeonardoSeccia It's the Application DbContext

Comment: I mean `trigger`...

Comment: The dbset associated with the "Trigger" model

Comment: Can you show us how you created it please...? ie. `new Trigger() { bla bla bla }` - the bla bla bla bit

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have anything like this,

```
private int _id = -1;
public int Id {get => _name; set => _name = value};
```

Just remove it and try this,

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

This solved my problem

Comment: A little more detail explaining why this works would be helpful.